# How Do I Show Unified Inbox Folder at Startup in ThunderBird?

Tags: thunderbird

I got ThunderBird set to show Unified mail view. The problem is when I start up ThunderBird, mail from the Inbox folder of the default account shows up. But I want mail from the Unified Inbox Folder to show as default when TB starts up. Is there a way to do this?